# Can I put undefined as a paramether in a method in react native?

Tags: react-native

I have list of results and I want to filter them by price. Here is my filter method:

```
 const filterResultsByPrice = price => {
     // price === '$' || '$$' || '$$$' || undefined
     return results.filter(result => {
         return result.price === price;
     });
};
```

Some of the objects which I need to show have price field equal to '$', '$$', '$$$', or undefined. I am showing the objects with price tag '$', '$$', '$$$' in the following way, which works correct, as expected:

```
  <ResultsList results={filterResultsByPrice("£")} title="Cost Effective" />
  <ResultsList results={filterResultsByPrice("££")} title="Bit Pricier" />
  <ResultsList results={filterResultsByPrice("£££")} title="Big Spender" />
```

My question is how do I show the objects which have 'undefined' for price? I tried `<ResultsList results={filterResultsByPrice(undefined)} title="Undefined" />` and indeed, it displayed the undefined priced objects, but it also gives me the following error: `source.uri should not be an empty string`

**EDIT** after a comment as more information is needed:
My ResultList component:

```
 const ResultsList = ({ title, results }) => {
   return (
     <View>
       <Text>We have found {results.length} results </Text>
       <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
       <FlatList
          horizontal
          data={results}
          keyExtractor={result => result.id}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            return <ResultsDetail result={item} />;
          }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

And my ResultsDetail component:

```
  const ResultsDetail = ({ result }) => {
     return (
       <View>
         <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: result.image_url }} />
         <Text style={styles.name}>{result.name}</Text>
         <Text>
           {result.rating} Stars, {result.review_count} Reviews
        </Text>
     </View>
   );
 };
```

Comment: I think there is some missing context here, do you display some sort of image for undefined? That error would occur in some sort of Image component.

Comment: @NoahGaeta Yes, I am displaying an image. I added more details.

Comment: Also, I am using yelp api if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess, `result.image_url` is null or undefined in the case of rendering the `ResultList` component where price is undefined. Ensure that the `result.image_url` contains a non-empty string, if you expect it to be empty then you can do this `<Image style={styles.image} source={result.image_url ? { uri: result.image_url }: {}} />` or just conditionally render the `Image` component. Here is what that would look like:

```
{result.image_url && (
     <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: result.image_url }} />
)}
```

Let me know if you have any more questions.